# Prove by contradiction (not using a calculator) that $\sqrt6 + \sqrt2 < \sqrt{15}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, number-comparison

> Prove by contradiction (not using a calculator) that $\sqrt6 + \sqrt2 < \sqrt{15}$.

How do you approach such a problem?  I need to admit that I'm completely new to proof writing and I have completely no experience in answering that kind of questions. I tried to square it as I read online but I'm stuck with having $\sqrt3$ and not knowing how to get rid of it to have the answer as clear as the sun.
squaring them yielded:
$(\sqrt2 + \sqrt6)^2 =  8 + 4\sqrt3 < 15$ which indeed holds but the problem is that I am not allowed to use calculator to check the little difference.

My final answer was $4\sqrt3 < 7$.

Comment: Why not try squaring again?

Comment: It seems that this problem appeared as an assignment [here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs173/fa2009/Homework/hw3_solutions.pdf), where you can also find a solution.

Comment: As on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286066/prove-by-contradicton-that-sqrt6-sqrt2-sqrt15), I mention that your first step when proving *anything* by contradiction is to contradict it.  Of course, moving on from there might be might or less difficult, but at least it gets you started!

Comment: Incidentally, you can find a solution [here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs173/fa2009/Homework/hw3_solutions.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let$$\sqrt6+\sqrt2\geq\sqrt{15}.$$
Thus,
$$8+2\sqrt{12}\geq15$$ or
$$4\sqrt3\geq7$$ or
$$48\geq49,$$
which is contradiction.

Id est, our assuming was wrong, which says
$$\sqrt6+\sqrt2<\sqrt{15}.$$

Comment: For what it's worth, since my students are very fond of using "let" where it doesn't belong, I should mention that you can't *let* $\sqrt6 + \sqrt2$ be greater than or equal to $\sqrt{15}$; it is or it isn't.  What you can do instead is *suppose* that the former is greater than or equal to the latter, and derivative a contradiction from the supposition.  (By way of contrast, although there's no reason to do so, you could begin your proof by saying "Let $x$ be $\sqrt{15}$"; since there's no $x$ yet, you can let it be whatever you want.)

Answer (score 3):

The claim is that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$, so its negation is simply the statement

> $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} < \sqrt{15}$ is false

or alternatively,

> $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \ge \sqrt{15}$

Now in order to prove the claim, suppose that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6} \ge \sqrt{15}$ and square both sides, getting

$$2 + 6 + 2\sqrt{12} \ge 15$$

Simplifying, this leads to

$$2 \sqrt{12} \ge 7$$

Do you see how to derive a contradiction now?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but recently mentioned. I wanted to comment that there is no gain from using contradiction:

A proof by contradiction is like

claim $2*3=6$. Proof: assume otherwise. But $2*3=3+3=6. $CONTRADICTION TO WHAT WE ASSUMED!!!!

Here is the first proof reconfigured. I tried to stick to the form there.

Claim: $$\sqrt6+\sqrt2\lt \sqrt{15}.$$
Proof:
Equivalently (squaring both sides) the claim is
$$8+2\sqrt{12}\lt 15$$ or
$$4\sqrt3\lt 7$$ or (squaring again)
$$48\lt 49,$$
which is true.

Id est, our claim is true , which says
$$\sqrt6+\sqrt2<\sqrt{15}.$$